# Is there a normal velocity of water flowing on a curved surface?

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics, flow, surface-tension

Is there a normal velocity of water flowing on a curved surface? If so, will this normal velocity cause water to be pulled? If so, will this pull reduce the pressure on the curved surface?
[image]
**Flowing water is a free surface.**

Comment: Check out Coanda effect.

Comment: @SolarMike Is there a normal velocity?

Comment: @enbinzheng The velocity at the separation point is zero due to viscosity. What type of fluid flow do you consider?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Ideal fluid.

Comment: @enbinzheng What is formed behind the point of separation - a gas cavity?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I'm just talking about moving on a curved surface.

Comment: @enbinzheng but you painted something like a waterfall.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I imagine it flows through channels.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I'm talking about water under gravity, which flows through a curved channel. Your answer seems to have no gravity.

Comment: @enbinzheng What difference is there gravity or not? I answered the question about the effect of channel curvature on velocity and pressure in an ideal fluid. Or are you interested in viscous flow?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Look at my picture, gravity is vertical downward, so the water will bend downward under the action of gravity. Can't a flow bend downward without gravity?

Comment: @enbinzheng You confuse the flow with a free surface under the influence of gravity, like a river, and the flow in a pipe with a given flow rate or with a given pressure difference. See Figure 2 for the viscous flow parameters in a vertical gravity field in a curved channel with a given flow rate.

Comment: @AlexTrounev What I want to know is the flow of a free surface and the flow under gravity.

Answer (score 1):

First, the normal velocity component is zero for both the ideal fluid and the viscous fluid, $\vec u.\vec n=0$.This condition means that the fluid cannot flow through the solid boundary. Sometimes there is a condition $\vec u.\vec n=q$, which means that there is blowing or sucking fluid through a porous wall. Secondly, the separation of the flow from the wall is usually due to the deceleration of the flow. In this case, a gas cavity or a return current may form. In both cases, the condition of no leakage is not violated,  $\vec u.\vec n=0$. Third, the pressure distribution depends on the flow. In the case of the flow of an ideal fluid in a curvilinear channel, the pressure increases on one wall and falls on the other, see Figure 1. Figure 1 shows the flow velocity (left) and pressure distribution (right) in the U-shaped channel.
[image: Figure 1]

In the case of viscous flow, the components of velocity and pressure at $Re=100$ are shown in Fig. 2. Figure 2 shows the viscous flow parameters in a vertical gravity field (on $z$ direction) in a curved channel with a given flow rate.

[image: fig2]